# How can I transfer Props from one component to another via Link

Tags: reactjs, routes, state, react-router-dom, react-props

[My Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-nobel-b1psb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The code shows that when you enter data in three lines, they must be transmitted via Link using the State method, but when you try to display them on the secStr page, it gives Undefined

Comment: Please post the relevant code *here*, not in an external repo; see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the withRouter HOC (high order component) into `secStr` page to have access to location props and the state data

Take a look at this:

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Something like this:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import {
  withRouter
} from "react-router";

class secStr extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return ( <
      div >
      date in inputs <
      br / >
      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(secStr);
```